# Schema export using oracle datapump

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, datapump

What are the objects will be exported while taking a full schema export using oracle datapump utility?

Comment: The entirety of the schema

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the schema.

External Table definitions will be included, but not the actual files on the OS that populate said tables.

There are some considerations for sequences you will need to take into account.

[The Docs have a list of these 'gotchas' here.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-1AD496E9-9CA3-456C-BFF2-3E9098370D70.htm#SUTIL3665)